# Make a JFace TableViewer resize with it's surrounding composite?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, jface, tableviewer

Using the WindowBuilder for Eclipse, I have created a `TableViewer` which I have placed inside a composite. (The `TableViewer` creates an SWT `Table`, in which the `TableViewer` itself is inserted).

I have tried to make the composite resizable by setting `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` and `grabVerticalSpace` to true, but how to I make also the table and the `TableViewer` fill the composite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to tell without code, but from your description you don't set a layout on your `Composite`. Try adding `composite.setLayout(new FillLayout());` if your composite contains only the TableViewer.

If your composite has more than one child, you'll need a different layout, like GridLayout, or MigLayout. Then you'll also have to set layoutData on your Table and the other children of your composite.

[Here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#gridlayout) are some snippets, which show how to use GridLayout. To learn MigLayout, which I find way better, see [here](http://miglayout.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, this was part of the solution. In addition, I also had to set SWT.FILL instead of SWT.LEFT and SWT.TOP in the setLayoutData(). I just solved this with help from #eclipse IRC channel, as documented in a separate answer.

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer now, (Big thanks to rcjsuen on the #eclipse channel on irc.freenode.net).

The code I had looked like this:
        Composite comp = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
        comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.TOP, true, true, 1, 1));

What I needed to do was, in addition to setting grabExcessiveHorizontalSpace and grabExcessiveVerticalSpace to true, (param 3 and 4 in the setLayoutData() function), to set param 1 and 2 to SWT.FILL, and also add a FillLayout object with the setLayout() function, like so:

```
    Composite comp = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    comp.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```